# SQL - Query between four tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I´m having a problem with a query.

```
select  p.id, p.firstname, p.lastname , max(s.year) as 'Last Year', min(s.year) as 'First Year', c.name from pilot p
join country on country.sigla = p.country
join circuit c on c.country_id = country.sigla
join season s
on(p.id = s.pilot_id)
group by p.id, p.firstname, p.lastname, c.name
order by p.id
```

Table Pilot

```
Id (Primary Key)
Name
Table Season
```

Table Season

```
Year (Primary key)
Pilot_id (Foreign Key)
```

Table Country

```
Sigla (Primary Key)
```

Table Cicuit

```
id (Primary Key)
name
```

The table Pilot is linked to Season and Country. And the table circuit is linked to Country.
I want to show for every pilot the last and the first circuit in every line, but the problem is that i'm having duplicate results. The first result shows me the 1st circuit and the duplicate shows me the last circuit. I'm having 67 results where i want to have only 40 ( the total number of pilots in the database)

Comment: Who is "e"? (e.year) and Why need you "season"? Remove "season" from query.

Comment: The table definitions do not include some columns that are referenced in the query e.g. `circuit.country_id`, What query would you use to find the "first" circuit for a given pilot? Or find the "last" circuit? From the table definitions shown, the only way to distinguish that would be use either the `id` column, the `name` column, or a combination of both.  There doesn't appear to be any other way to order the rows from `circuit`. It looks like a pilot is related to at most one country, and therefore a pilot is related to every circuit related to that same country. How do you order the circuit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowed answer from above with further explanation because I couldn't comment on it.
You'll need to write subqueries for the first year and the last year to use different select criteria for each. For the first year, you want to order by the year ASC to get the smallest year in the column. For last year, you'll want to order by year DESC to get the largest year in the column.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT p.id
        ,p.firstname
        ,p.lastname
        ,FirstCircuit = (
            SELECT TOP 1 circuitname
            FROM circuit c
            WHERE p.id = c.id
            ORDER BY year ASC
            )
        ,LastCircuit = (
            SELECT TOP 1 circuitname
            FROM circuit c
            WHERE p.id = c.id
            ORDER BY year DESC
            )
    FROM pilot p
    INNER JOIN country ON country.sigla = p.country
    INNER JOIN season s ON (p.id = s.pilot_id)
    ) tbl
GROUP BY id
    ,firstname
    ,lastname
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: With this query pattern, the value returned for `FirstCircuit` or `LastCircuit` is going to be indeterminate. Ordering by a column reference to a table in the outer query (`year` is in `season` table)... every `year` is associated with every `circuit`.   And the predicate in the subquery just looks wrong... the `id` value of the `circuit` table has to match the `id` value of the `pilot` table. And there's no explanation about why would we would want to query every `circuit` from every `country`, and not just the `circuit` that are related to the `country` the pilot is related to.

Answer (score 0):

use inline sql like this edited one as per your tables

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT p.id
        ,p.firstname
        ,p.lastname
        ,FirstCircuit = (
            SELECT TOP 1 circuitname
            FROM circuit c
            WHERE p.id = c.id
            ORDER BY year ASC
            )
        ,LastCircuit = (
            SELECT TOP 1 circuitname
            FROM circuit c
            WHERE p.id = c.id
            ORDER BY year DESC
            )
    FROM pilot p
    INNER JOIN country ON country.sigla = p.country
    INNER JOIN season s ON (p.id = s.pilot_id)
    ) tbl
GROUP BY id
    ,firstname
    ,lastname
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is with the join to the `circuit` table.

There's no need to replace the `MIN(s.year)` and `MAX(s.year)` expressions in the select list. (Despite what other answers recommend, that does nothing to address the real issue... getting a result that meets the specification to return only *one* row per pilot.)

Start debugging this by starting with a simpler query... join just the `pilot` table and the `season` table. For example:

```
 select p.id
      , p.firstname
      , p.lastname
      , max(s.year) as 'Last Year'
      , min(s.year) as 'First Year'
   from pilot p
   join season s
     on p.id = s.pilot_id
  group by p.id, p.firstname, p.lastname
  order by p.id
```

That should return, at most, one row per `pilot` (given that `id` is unique in the `pilot` table.)  Rows in `pilot` that don't have any associated rows in `season` will be excluded, due to the inner join.

When you add in the joins to the other tables (`country` and `circuit`) you have the potential to introduce duplicate rows. But those rows will get "collapsed" into a single row for each pilot.

It's when you include `c.name` in the `GROUP BY`, that's when your "duplicate" rows start appearing in your result set.  With that expression in the `GROUP BY` clause, you have the potential to get back more than one row for each pilot.

That's where the issue is.

You will be guaranteed that the rows returned will have distinct values of `c.name` for each pilot.

To fix that, you could remove `c.name` from the `GROUP BY` clause, and use an aggregate expression in the select list, for example `MAX(c.name)`.

That query would return (at most) one row per pilot. (Again, if there are no rows in `circuit` associated with a `country` associated with a pilot, then those pilot rows will be excluded.)

```
 select p.id
      , p.firstname
      , p.lastname
      , max(s.year) as 'Last Year'
      , min(s.year) as 'First Year'
      , max(c.name) as circuit_name
   from pilot p
   join season s
     on p.id = s.pilot_id
   join country 
     on country.sigla = p.country
   join circuit c
     on c.country_id = country.sigla
  group by p.id, p.firstname, p.lastname
  order by p.id
```

---

On the bit about returning the "first and last circuit on each line"...

How do you determine which circuit is "first" and which circuit is "last" for each pilot?  The only two columns we see in the table are `id` and `name`. And the only relationship (shown) between a `pilot` and a `circuit` is through the `country` table. A `pilot` only has one `country`, so a pilot is associated with every circuit in that `country`.